# Different conditions for different fields in thinking-sphinx

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :new_post, with: :real_time do
  indexes title, sortable: true
  indexes text

  has state, type: :string
  has forum_hidden, type: :boolean
  has created_at, type: :timestamp
  has publish_at, type: :timestamp
  has reminde_at, type: :timestamp
  has deleted_at, type: :timestamp
  has content_category_ids, type: :integer, multi: true
end
```

And let's i need to get all the records where @title=query with any value publish_at or @text=query with publish_at = 1.month.ago..Time.current

That is, I need to combine these two requests:

```
NewPost.search(conditions: { title: query })
NewPost.search(conditions: { text: query }, with: { publish_at: 1.month.ago..Time.current })
```

The result is needed with excerpts

**UPDATE**

published_at interval for the @title and @text fields is always different and depends on the user's rights. For example, there can be such a situation:

```
NewPost.search(conditions: { title: query }, with: { publish_at: 1.year.ago..Time.current })
NewPost.search(conditions: { text: query }, with: { publish_at: 6.month.ago..Time.current })
```

and all results that do not fall under these conditions should not be displayed at all

Comment: Having now seen the edit, you probably have no choice than to just run two queries, and merge... doubt ts has a union feature

Answer (score 0):

The main thing when wanting to 'combine' multiple criteria is deciding on a 'calculation' how to compute a weight that gives that effect. Sphinx computes a weight and orders by that. Rather than unions of multiple distinct queries

For example
https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/searching.html#sorting

```
ThinkingSphinx.search(
  :select => '*, WEIGHT() + IF(publish_at>NOW()-2592000,1000,0) AS custom_weight',
  :order  => 'custom_weight DESC'
)
```

would use a the 'full-text' search weight, but add 1000 if in last month.

Uses the sphinx NOW() function 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#expr-func-now

You might also want field weights
https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/searching.html#fieldweights
to boost `title` matches over 'text' matches

```
:field_weights => { :title=>10 }
```

Bringing all togehter (if got the ruby syntax right... )

```
NewPost.search( query , 
  :select => '*, weight() + IF(publish_at>NOW()-2592000,1000,0) as custom_weight',
  :order  => 'custom_weight DESC', 
  :field_weights => { :title=>10 }
)
```

... in theory title matches will be first. And recent ones towards start too. Not EXACTLY what you asked for, but close.